# How do I select last child of input type text in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I get the last child of input type text inside an nGfor ? 
For first child:

```html
span:first-child > input[type=text]
```

it works just fine but for last-child the dom doesn't seem to have a last-child..Angular 6 here.

Comment: it works for last child too https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngstyle-examples-acbg6k. can you provide problem in this stackblitz?

Comment: @FatemeFazli add another input type like a button and it won't work

Comment: now check the stackblitz again.

Comment: yes, I agree but my angular html structure will be this one: https://pastebin.com/fycs1pgj

Answer (score 1):

You can use ViewChildren (in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uuvccb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) if you open the page in new window, at first the last element get the focus, each time you push "add button" the last element get the focus too.

The idea is has a series of inputs with reference name, e.g. input

```
<p *ngFor="let i of elements"><input #input ></p>
```

You define

```
  @ViewChildren('input') inputs:QueryList<ElementRef>
```

In ngAfterViewInit

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.inputs.last.nativeElement.focus()

    this.inputs.changes.subscribe(() => {
        this.inputs.last.nativeElement.focus()
    })
  }
```

We must subscribe to this.inputs.changes if our code allow change the number of inputs.

NOTE:In the stackblitz I use a tipical pipe(takeWhile(()=>this.alive) to unsubscribe on Destroy the component

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to change the class of the last item, so I used [Eliseo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55086942/5747727) code but instead of listening to changes I just check if that element is last item in elements in creation time. maybe you do not need that listening complexity.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l5ccns

```
<button (click)="elements.push(1)">add</button>
<p *ngFor="let i of elements; let ind = index"><input #input [ngClass]="{'lastItem': ind === elements.length-1}" ></p>
```